# How to declare $this as an *use()* parameter in an anonymous function?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

Example:

```
class foo {
    private $x=array();
    public function foo() {
        $z = function ($a) use (&$this->x) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR:** Cannot use $this as lexical variable

---

Conform to situation, we can declare the anonymous as a method... so another problem arrives. My "real case",

```
// a very specific problem...
class foo {
    private $x=array();

    public function foo($m) {
    // ... use $this->x and $m ...
    return $ret;
}

    public function bar() {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/aaaa/', $this->foo, $str);
    }
}
```

ERROR: Undefined property $foo ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** it looks like your callback should be an object method, not a closure, if you need to modify that private property from the callback. So:

```
preg_replace_callback('/aaaa/', array($this, 'foo'), $str);
```

Where `foo` is your method. But if the property doesn't need to be modified, using a closure as callback and assigning the value of `x` to a variable which you `use` is fine.

---

I should also mention that from PHP 5.4 you can access `$this` from within closures:

```
preg_replace_callback('/aaaa/', function($a){
  // $this->x is accessible here
}, $str);
```

Comment: Yes, coping, a non-elegant solution...  No better "escape syntax" with PHP??

Comment: Well the elegant solution is to make `$z` a method :)

Comment: Yes, good ideia to make the anonymous function as a method. I edited the question to you see a new problem.

Comment: PS: can I edit yor answer to add pointer `$that = &$this->x` as Bgdan, and add the magnific solution for my specific problem... or you edit? (then I can accept)

Comment: References, or pointers as you call them are not needed here. I've updated the A.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class foo {
    private $x=array();
    public function foo() {
        $v = &$this->x;
        $z = function ($a) use ($v) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, coping a pointer, a non-elegant solution... No better "escape syntax" with PHP??

Comment: That is most robust and that which I would trust

Comment: What's the `&` for? The closure doesn't get a reference. You need `use(&$v)` too. And passing by reference a private property to an anon. function breaks fundamental OO concepts :) You might as well make the property public then